# Order of execution in python's `print` function

Tags: python, stdout, wrapper, python-unittest

I have a function wrapper for my test cases that keeps track of how much time the function takes, then outputs some basic info using `print`. The code for my function wrapper is below:

```
TEST_INIT_START = datetime.datetime.now()

def timedisplay(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        try:
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            print()
            print(
                'Total time elapsed:',
                (datetime.datetime.now() - TEST_INIT_START).seconds,
                'seconds',
            )
            print(
                f'{func.__name__} test time elapsed:',
                (datetime.datetime.now() - start).seconds,
                'seconds',
            )
            print('Result: ', end='')
    return wrapper
```

The expected output for a test case using this wrapper would be something like:

```
test_some_function (tests.test_some_function) ...
Total time elapsed: 2 seconds
test_some_function test time elapsed: 2 seconds
Result: ok
```

But the weird thing is this is what I'm actually getting:

```
test_some_function (tests.test_some_function) ... Result: 
Total time elapsed: 2 seconds
test_some_function test time elapsed: 2 seconds
ok
```

For some reason the output is getting written to the console with the final print statement first. My first thought would be that the calls to `datetime.datetime.now()` are releasing the GIL and executing the most simple statement before it's required, but I don't have any information to back that up. My question is mainly *why* this would be happening, and how to get it to execute properly.

Comment: Where does `ok` come from? It looks like you are assuming you can inject the output in the `finally` block in the middle of some string output by the wrapped function.

Comment: What exactly does `timedisplay` get applied to?

Comment: Does adding `flush=True` to the print statements solve this issue?

Comment: I have seen such output mixups when there was output to stderr and stdout, then the two streams aren't necessarily flushed at the same time, but this is weird, since all your print statements a sent to the same stream. I have to ask the dumb question, are you sure this output really from this exact code?

Comment: It would help us if you made your example complete, so it can be reproducible. Provide a dummy function you've wrapped, and show us how you wrap and call it, so we can just cut and paste your code is run it on our own as is.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: when I wrap my own dummy function, which just prints "ok", I get `ok\n\nTotal time elapsed: 0 seconds\nmyfunc test time elapsed: 0 seconds\nResult:` exactly as I would have expected.

Comment: @chepner The `ok` statement is from the `unittest` module. `timedisplay` wraps the functions inside my test case

Comment: The order of execution has to be 1) what's in `func` *followed* by the finally block in the order it is written.

Comment: Ah, that might be the issue: `unittest` can capture and handle the output for you, so it's possible the print statements are being sent to different buffers that get handled separately.

Comment: @joanis Yeah, this is definitely a solution, but I'm still very curious as to why this is happening. It seems very odd considering the `print` functionality is so basic and consistent

Comment: I'm confident `unittest` is voiding our assumptions here. A lot of stuff gets monkey-patched by that system, so "basic" things might not always work the way you expect. The order of execution of those print statements will be the same, but when their output gets flushed to screen might be out of your control.

Comment: @joanis I think you're right. Something might be happening with `stdout` underneath the `unittest` functionality. I was working under the assumption that it's just essentially "wrapping" the test case functions with output before and after to print the status/result. I noticed that it appears to have something to do with the comma-separated values inside `print`, because putting it all in the same `print` using commas is giving the same output as the original